# Collapsed navbar on iPad - weird behaviour on expansion

Tags: html, css, web, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap on my website. One of the things is the navbar. It works fine on desktop, iPhone etc., but on my iPad it looks like this (transparent background and white font):

[image: eImage]

What am I doing wrong?

I didn't use any CSS on it, so it's all Bootstrap's.

```
<nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse bg-inverse">
            <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Kev's Kitchen</a>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                   <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="meetTheChef.html">Meet the Chef</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to the site?

Comment: http://kev.rc8.me/index.html

Comment: Can you describe what exactly is wrong with the site when you open it on Ipad?  I dont see anything wrong with the picture you posted...

Comment: you need to look closely. I expanded the menu and the  background of the menu is transparent and the font white, for some odd reason.

Comment: What version of Bootstrap 4 are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem. Just add 
`.navbar {display: block !important;}`
to your CSS

Answer (score 0):

You should start by cleaning up the header of your page. Accumulating all sorts of outdated garbage in your header is not exactly a smart idea...

Next step is to delete ALL contents of the app.css file and start using native Bootstrap classes to achieve what you want instead of manually overwriting everything. Native Bootstrap classes can get done pretty much everything you'll ever need.

P.S. It's always a bad idea to use the `!important` flag as suggested in the other answer. Using the `!important` flag suggests that you have no idea what you're doing. It is certainly not needed in this case.

Before you use this kind of stuff:

```html
    .container-fluid {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
```

...you should learn about the Bootstrap grid and layout. Because then you'll realize that when you use Bootstrap the way it's intended to be used none of that custom css is necessary anymore.